# Ignore String When "Enter" Key is Pressed

Tags: string, scanf

I have a question concerning this line of code:

```
scanf("%s %s %s", &op, &s1, &s2);
opPtr = &op;
s1Ptr = &s1;
s2Ptr = &s2;

if (strcmp(opPtr, "^") == 0 && (strcmp(s1Ptr, "A") == 0) && (strcmp(s2Ptr, "") == 0))
    matrix_transpose(matA, ArowsPtr, AcolsPtr);
```

My `scanf(op, s1, s2)` is to get the user to enter an operation on two matrices (s1 and s2) and an operation on them (op). This includes op = "*" || "+" || "^" where "^" is a transpose.

For a transpose I need only s1. So the user would enter "^ A[ENTER]" and matA, ArowsPtr and AcolsPtr would be invoked into the matrix_transpose function.

My problem is that I don't understand how to ignore s2Ptr when the operation entered is '^' . I tried setting s2Ptr to an empty string and adding '\n' to strcmp(s1Ptr, "A\n") == 0
but that doesn't help ignore s2.

I'm assuming there's need in creating a while(EOF) of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%s %s %s", &op, &s1, &s2);
```

This line can't be well defined, because of the types of `&op`, `&s1` and `&s2`. They're expected by `scanf` to be `char *`s, but the only way that can happen is if `op`, `s1` and `s2` are declared like: `char op, s1, s2;`. This would imply that your input fields are zero characters, at the most.

More likely is that you've declared `op`, `s1` and `s2` are declared like: `char op[max], s1[max], s2[max];`. That means the types of `&op`, `&s1` and `&s2` are `char (*)[max]`. These pointers may point to the same place, but they're not required to have the same representation. It's only by coincidence that they do have the same representation, on your system. If you care about portability, you'll develop an understanding that arrays silently convert to pointers, and use something like this instead:

```
/* TODO: Handle errors from scanf! */
assert(scanf("%s %s %s", op, s1, s2) == 3);
```

`scanf` interprets a space in it's format string as "read as many whitespace characters as possible". `'\n'` is counted as whitespace. So when you enter "^ A\n" into stdin, `scanf` has read and stored two of your *words*, and is waiting for the third. This might explain why it appears as though you can't ignore the third. Perhaps you could read one of your words, then check whether or not the `op` is `"^"` before deciding how many more you want to retrieve. For example:

```
/* TODO: Handle errors from scanf! */
assert(scanf("%s", op) == 1);

if (strcmp(op, "^") == 0) {
    assert(scanf("%s", s1) == 1);
    if (strcmp(s1, "A") == 0) {
        matrix_transpose(matA, ArowsPtr, AcolsPtr);
    }
}
else {
    assert(scanf("%s %s", s1, s2) == 2);
    /* TODO: Do something with s1 and s2... */
}
```